# python django continous checking for validation of user and date

Tags: python, django

I have models :

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user

class Winner(models.Model):
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    win_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user
```

Here what I want is go generate a winner randomly from my Participant model.

I want to check if the randomly generated winner has won the game in past then I want to check if the won date difference between last time and now is greater then 4 month. If it is greater then user can win the game else again generate random user.

For this I have done:

```
player_list = Participant.objects.all()
winner = random.choice(player_list)
next_check = Winner.objects.filter(user=winner) 
if next_check:
    if (date.today() - timedelta(days= 4*365/12)) > next_check.win_date.date():
    #what if the user has won 5 times in past
        final_winner = winner
    else:
        # Again generate winner randomy and again check for the date is greater than 4 month
```

I have gone with this :

```
final_winner = None
while not final_winner:
    winner = random.choice(player_list)
    next_check = Winner.objects.filter(user=winner)
    if next_check:
    #wht if the user has won previously and what if the user has won many times previously
        if (date.today() - timedelta(days= 4*365/12)) > next_check.win_date.date():
            final_winner = winner
```

Can anyone guide me through this .

Thank you

Comment: `Winner` model doesn't have a `user` field. or does it?

Comment: It does not..... I am just saving the user that I am getting from api not form django user model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your model hierarchy is not well-designed. Both `Participant` and `Winner` models serve to similar purposes and have the same fields.

Moreover, it looks like `Participant` is the superset of `Winner` since everyone will be defined as participant at first than one of them will win the game and become a winner. So, I would recommend you to create  `Winner` by [subclassing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#inheritance-and-reverse-relations) from `Participant` and define same fields in the super class like below:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.email

class Winner(Participant):
    win_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

One beautiful thing about this approach is that Django will create an implicit `OneToOneField` field from winner to participant so you'll be directly connected to participant details of a winner automatically.

---

As for your actual question, about checking if a user has won any game in the last 4 months, you can do the following:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

def has_won_any_game_since(user, period):
    return Winner.objects.filter(user=user, win_date__gt=now() - period).exists()

def get_random_winner():
    player_list = list(Participant.objects.all())
    four_months = timedelta(days=120) # ~4 months

    while len(player_list) > 0:
        player = random.choice(player_list)
        if not has_won_any_game_since(player.user, four_months):
            return player
        else:
            player_list.remove(player)
    else:
        return None
```

---

```
>>> winner = get_random_winner()
<Winner: ozgur@winner.com, win_date='07/23/2014 07:23:86'> # win_date is supposed to be less than 120 days.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if my user in not from django user model and I am saving it from api that is sending me the users

Comment: You are just checking it in the Winner model. Randomly generated user might has won previously but not necessary that it should be in Winner table. I just want if the randomly generated user has won previously and its last won date is not greater than 4 month than generate new user else if the generated user is not in the Winner table the just show the winner is randomly generated user